# Usar o evento Click dentro de um IF

Tags: c#

Olá, gostaria de saber se é possível usar um evento Click dentro de um IF. Vou tentar explicar a minha situação. De momento tenho isto:

```
foreach (Label lblCor in panel1.Controls)

    if (lblNum.Text == lblCor.Text)
    {
        lblCor.Click += new EventHandler(lblCor_Click);
        lblCor.BackColor = Color.Orange;
    }

    private void lblCor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Estou a tentar fazer com que quando a lblNum.text seja igual á lblCor.Text, e clique na lblCor, esta mesma mude de cor. Será possível fazer isto?

Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de criar os eventos, faça lá a comparação.

```
private void lblCor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var lbl = (Label)sender;

    if (lbl.Text == lblNum.Text)
    {
        lbl.BackColor = Color.Orange;
    }
}
```

Comment: O problema é que eu tenho painéis diferentes e cada um desses painéis têm 27 Labels. E eu desta forma não consigo usar isto para todas as Labels

Comment: Se tem paineis diferentes tem que fazer o foreach (que adiciona o evento) para cada um deles... ou achar outro jeito de criar o evento para todas as labels...ou até mesmo manualmente atraves do seu_form.designer.cs

Answer (score -2):

Tente fazer essa verificação dentro do método `lblCor_Click`. Desta forma você não precisaria colocar o lançamento do evento dentro do *loop*.

Ex:

```
private void lblCor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (lblNum.Text == lblCor.Text)
        {
             lblCor.Click += new EventHandler(lblCor_Click);
             lblCor.BackColor = Color.Orange;
        }
}
```

Desta forma quando o usuário realizar o evento de click haverá a comparação e mudança de cor desejada.

Comment: Você percebeu que `lblCor` é um item de uma lista?

Comment: Não está a dar o resultado que desejava, mas obrigado